# why I can't add Group View in android?

Tags: android, view, radio-button

I add Group Radio in View (android.view.View)

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);        
     radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
     {
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             //---displays the ID of the RadioButton that is checked---
             System.out.printf(String.format("\n Id : %d", checkedId));
         }
     });
```

But syntax error, it show:

```
02-07 21:10:09.918: E/AndroidRuntime(230): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.v2nhat.myPikachu.View.QuickPlayView.selectLevel(QuickPlayView.java:28)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.v2nhat.myPikachu.View.QuickPlayView.onTouchEvent(QuickPlayView.java:51)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-07 21:10:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(230):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When I call that code. Error at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because most likely you imported (or your IDE did) the wrong class (for example `CheckBox` also has an `OnCheckedChangeListener()`). Try with

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new Radio.OnCheckedChangeListener()
```

Or remove/fix the wrong imports.

Comment: it's still not working.<br> I import "import android.widget.RadioGroup;"

Comment: Well if you don't show us what errors, we can't help further.

Comment: syntax error: "The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){})"

Comment: Then you didn't change the code or you didn't recompile the classes.

Comment: Thanks, Its working. I edited : radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()

Comment: That's a problem with your code. I don't have the code that throws the error, but it's an null object you're trying to use in `com.v2nhat.myPikachu.View.QuickPlayView.selectLevel(QuickPlayView.java:28)`. This anyway has nothing to do with your original question.